# scala save to array with format

Tags: scala

I have two `val`s:

```
// 0~250::250~500::500~750::750~1000
val step_x_ranges = stepsAsString.mkString("::")

// 1::22::7::16
val step_y = histogram_final.map{case (x , y) => y}.mkString("::")
```

And I want to save it to an `Array` like:

```
0~250::1
250~500::22
500~750::7
750::1000::16
```

But still not try out:
Please help me

Here is my wrong code:

```
var toArray : Array[String] = Array()
   for (i <- 0 to 3)
   {
     val ArrayRow = step_x_ranges(i) + "::" + step_y(i)
     toArray = toArray :+ ArrayRow
   }
   println(toArray(0)) 
   println(toArray(1))
```

Result:

```
0::4
~::8
```

Comment: Do you want to zip these `Seq`s? https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch10s24.html : `stepsAsString.zip(histogramFinal).map(...`

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip`:

```
scala> val step_x_ranges = Array("0~250", "250~500", "500~750","750~1000")
step_x_ranges: Array[String] = Array(0~250, 250~500, 500~750, 750~1000)

scala> val step_y = Array(1, 22, 7, 16)
step_y: Array[Int] = Array(1, 22, 7, 16)

scala> val result = step_x_ranges.zip(step_y).map{case (x, y) => s"$x::$y"}
res1: Array[String] = Array(0~250::1, 250~500::22, 500~750::7, 750~1000::16)
scala> scala.tools.nsc.io.File("test.txt").writeAll(result.mkString("\n"))
```

And test.txt:

```
0~250::1
250~500::22
500~750::7
750~1000::16
```

Comment: You are right! I get ````Vector(0~250::1, 250~500::22, 500~750::7, 750~1000::16)```` But how can I save this to a txt file ? ```` 0~250::1
250~500::22
500~750::7
750::1000::16````

Comment: I added saving to file to my answer. Use` mkString(" ")` if you need saving in one row.

Comment: I met an error :````Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/io/AbstractFile$```` Do you know this?

Comment: @user2492364, scala or Spark version mismatch, maybe?

Comment: @Paul has a good idea. IIn addition if you use spark and your data is rdd, then you should use result.saveAsTextFile("pathToFile"). Anyway there is not enough information about your problem, you would better create another example with your configs.